# How to click on an element based on coordinates and how to retrieve element properties with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, dom, click, casperjs

I would like to get attributes about objects using CasperJS, for example I have something like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://www.seznam.cz', function() {
    if (this.exists('div#info')) {
        require('utils').dump(this.getElementInfo('div#info'));
    } 
    else {
        this.echo(' not found', 'ERROR');
    }
});
casper.run();
```

I can see in console many attributes for example position of the element. Now given this, is it somehow possible to get these coordinates and perform for example `this.click(coordinates)`? If it is, how?

I also would like to know hot to get another properties, like `parentNode`, `childNodes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see in console many attributes for example position of the element. Now given this, is it somehow possible to get these coordinates and perform for example `this.click(coordinates)`? If it is, how?

A function like `casper.getElementInfo(selector)` provides the coordinates and dimensions of the first element matched by the given selector. It would be strange if CasperJS wouldn't have the ability to use those.

CasperJS has multiple modules for different task. One of those is the [mouse module](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/docs/modules/mouse.rst). This module provide a [`click()`](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/docs/modules/mouse.rst#click) function that either takes a selector or the coordinates to click somewhere.

```
casper.then(function(){
    var info = this.getElementInfo('div#info');
    this.mouse.click(info.x+1, info.y+1);
});
```

`+1` is necessary so that the element is actually clicked and not its border.

> I also would like to know hot to get another properties, like `parentNode`, `childNodes`.

This is much more difficult. CasperJS (and PhantomJS) has two contexts. The outer context is the code that you have in your script, but not completely. `casper.evaluate()` is the window into the sandboxed page context.

The function that is passed into `casper.evaluate()` has no access to variables defined outside. Values have to be explicitly passed. They will be serialized as JSON along the way. So when you want to pass DOM nodes out of the page context, they will lose their meaning, because they are not JSON serializable.

What you can do on the other hand, is to never pass the DOM nodes that you get when you call `parentNode` or `childNodes` outside. Only work with them completely in the page context. Store them on the global `window` object for later use for example and then use another `casper.evaluate()` later in your script to access them.

If you don't actually need the actual nodes, you can retrieve a representation of those nodes. The `textContent` is a good candidate for it:

```
var childContentsArray = casper.evaluate(function(){
    return [].map.call(document.querySelector("#someId").childNodes, function(child){
        return child.textContent;
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok know I am getting into the difference between Page and Casperjs context, just one question is it some way to get classname atributes of a child ? I did try return child.className, but this do not works.

Comment: There is a difference between `element.children` and `element.childNodes`. `childNodes` will also include TextNodes that don't have a `className`. Other than that, it should work.

Comment: You mentioned that I can use objects in another evaluate to access them, I have some link this: 
var search = 'div';
var atribute = 'id';

var divs = casper.evaluate(function(search){
   return elements = __utils__.findAll(search);
}, search);
  
var divIDS2 = casper.evaluate(function(divs, atribute){
   divs.map(function(e) {
    return e.getAttribute(atribute); 
   });
}, divs, atribute);

I do know how to get all div's id in just one function evaluate, but I do not know how to get it in two evaluates functions.

Comment: As I said, you cannot pass DOM nodes out of the page context. So don't return them in the first `casper.evaluate()`, but instead set them to `window`: `casper.evaluate(function(search){ window.myelements = __utils__.findAll(search); }, search);`. You can then later access `window.myelements` in a second `casper.evaluate()` call. The question is, why do you want to do this? In this case, you don't get anything out of splitting this into multiple `evaluate()` calls.

Comment: I know that functionality is same, but I am trying to implement algorithm which compares many atributes of elements and storing them in some variable can  be much more readable than many ifs in one evaluate function.